# Python Pandas filtering dataframe on date

Tags: python, pandas, csv, date

I am trying to manipulate a CSV file on a certain date in a certain column.
I am using pandas (total noob) for that and was pretty successful until i got to dates.
The CSV looks something like this (with more columns and rows of course).
These are the columns:

> Circuit
>   Status
>   Effective Date

These are the values:

> XXXX001
>   Operational
>   31-DEC-2007

I tried dataframe query (which i use for everything else) without success.
I tried dataframe loc (which worked for everything else) without success.

How can i get all rows that are older or newer from a given date? If i have other conditions to filter the dataframe, how do i combine them with the date filter?

Here's my "raw" code:

```
import pandas as pd
# parse_dates = ['Effective Date']
# dtypes = {'Effective Date': 'str'}
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv", dtype=object)
# , parse_dates=parse_dates, infer_datetime_format=True
# tried lot of suggestions found on SO
cols = df.columns
cols = cols.map(lambda x: x.replace(' ', '_'))
df.columns = cols

status1 = 'Suppressed'
status2 = 'Order Aborted'
pool = '2'
region = 'EU'
date1 = '31-DEC-2017'

filt_df = df.query('Status != @status1 and Status != @status2 and Pool == @pool and Region_A == @region')
filt_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
filt_df.to_csv('filtered.csv')
# this is working pretty well

supp_df = df.query('Status == @status1 and Effective_Date < @date1')
supp_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
supp_df.to_csv('supp.csv')
# this is what is not working at all
```

I tried many approaches, but i was not able to put it together. This is just one of many approaches i tried.. so i know it is perhaps completely wrong, as no date parsing is used.
supp.csv will be saved, but the dates present are all over the place, so there's no match with the "logic" in this code.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you convert your date to datetime and then filter slice on it.

```
df['Effective Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Effective Date'])
df[df['Effective Date'] < '2017-12-31']

#This returns all the values with dates before 31th of December, 2017.
#You can also use Query
```

Comment: Thank you. This is working. Now i have to figure out how to filter "bad" dates.. :)

Comment: @iDrwish...how to filter the date as ( 14 days before till current date)

Comment: You can use `timedelta` as in `dt.now() - timedelta(days=14)`, this is the date 14 days back.